# Git push writes more and more objects every time I do it

Tags: git, push, git-push

```
Enumerating objects: 85, done.
Counting objects: 100% (85/85), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (78/78), done.
Writing objects:  15% (13/84), 41.26 MiB | 46.00 KiB/s
```

It does this every time, I removed some files and it still increased, and when it was nearing the end last time it errored out with:

```
Enumerating objects: 75, done.
Counting objects: 100% (75/75), done.
Delta compression using up to 8 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (69/69), done.
remote: fatal: pack exceeds maximum allowed size
error: remote unpack failed: index-pack abnormal exit
To ssh://github.com/adobug/SSST2022Hackathon.git
 ! [remote rejected] main -> main (failed)
error: failed to push some refs to 'ssh://github.com/adobug/SSST2022Hackathon.git'
```

Comment: It doesn't look like it increased to me. It went from 85 objects to 75.

Answer (score 0):

When you make new commits, you *add to the repository*.

Suppose you have a Git repository with 100 commits.  You make one new commit, in which you add a big file (say, a 400 gigabyte database).  You now have 101 commits.

But—oops!—you didn't *mean* to commit the 400 gigabyte database.  So you run `git rm big-database.db` and then `git commit`.  You now have ... 102 commits, with the big file in the commit before the last one.

No matter what you do, as you add more commits, you *add* to the database.  You can't make a big file in history go away by *adding more history*.  You're going to have to *remove history*.  This may horrify some folks ([How to cope with mutable Git history?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70957184/1256452)) but Git *does* allow you to "reset yourself back in time" (`git reset`) and then make *new and improved commits* to use *instead of* the old bad ones.  The old bad commits *are not yet gone*, but your `git push` won't try to send *those* commits now; instead, it will send only your new and improved commits.

For more, see, e.g., [How to remove/delete a large file from commit history in the Git repository?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2100907/1256452) and its many duplicates.